# Lua redis In transit encryption connection

Tags: security, lua, redis, connection

I'm using [redis-lua](https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua) module. How can I connect to an in-transit enabled redis server in my lua script? I'm using AWS elastic cache, I've enabled [in-transit encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html).

Lua script which I'm using to connect with a redis instance without in-transit encryption enabled is given below,

```
local redis = require 'redis'
local client = redis.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379)
local response = client:ping()
```

From my another node.js script, I've found a solution to connect to an in-transit encryption enabled instance from,
[Securing Node Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947527/securing-node-redis)

The code which I've tried is given below. and is working fine not reliable, but, Is there any module available out there, or any reliable solution.

```
local ssl = require "ssl"
local socket = require "socket"
local params = {
    mode = "client",
    protocol = "tlsv1",
    verify = "none",
    options = "all",
}
local tcp_socket = socket.tcp()
tcp_socket:connect("xxxxxxxxxx", "6379")
local conn  = ssl.wrap(tcp_socket, params)
conn:dohandshake()
conn:send("AUTH testing\n\n")
conn:send("SET test tcp\n\n")
local line, err = conn:receive()
print(err or line)
conn:close()
```

Cheers

Comment: Share your script. Explain what you are wanting to do and what you have tried. Then others can help you more effectively.

Comment: @Brian added more details.

Comment: @Brian Do you need more details?

Comment: @Brian I've added the code which I've tried

Comment: I'll take a look asap - just haven't had the time yet. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian I've found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redis-lua module supports multiple way of giving the connection parameters. One of the way is to provide the created socket in the table like,

```
{
    socket = <socket>
}
```

To connect to an in-transit encryption enabled redis elastic cache,

```
local ssl = require "ssl"
local socket = require "socket"
local redis = require "redis"
local config = {
    host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    port = "6379",
    password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
local params = {
    mode = "client",
    protocol = "tlsv1",
    verify = "none",
    options = "all",
}
local tcp_socket = socket.tcp()
tcp_socket:connect(config.host, config.port)
local conn  = ssl.wrap(tcp_socket, params)
conn:dohandshake()
local client = redis.connect({
    socket = conn
})
client:auth(config.password)
print(client:ping())
```